# Php change 1k to 1000

Tags: php, numbers

i want to make a variable when transforms 1k or 1,5k into 1000 or 1500

i tried preg_replace but i doesn't work for me becasue it adds "000" to number so i'd get 1000 and 1,5000

thank you

Comment: What specific regular expression did you try with `preg_replace`?

Comment: why not removing 'k' and multiplying *1000?

Comment: Once you've got the k converted to its numerical equivalent, you can add the pretty formatting with `number_format()`.

Comment: i want to multiply it by 1000 but i don't know how :D

Comment: can you please explain whether you want to create a `variable` or a `function()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function expand_k($str) {
    // If the str does not end with k, return it unchanged.
    if ($str[strlen($str) - 1] !== "k") {
        return $str;
    }

    // Remove the k.
    $no_k = str_replace("k", "", $str);
    $dotted = str_replace("," , ".", $no_k);

    return $dotted * 1000;
}    

$a = "1k";
$b = "1,5k";

$a_expanded = expand_k($a);
$b_expanded = expand_k($b);

echo $a_expanded;
echo $b_expanded;
```

Outputs "1000" and "1500".  [You can see for yourself here.](http://codepad.org/uWMT9dHd)

Answer (score 2):

You should try to remove the k and multiply the result with 1000.

```
$digit = "1,5k";
$digit = str_replace(k, "", $digit);
$digit *= 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Crete a function and in that function do an if statement that checks for ',' and if it found it you can add 00 and not 000. Also in that function you could check for not only 'k', but also 'kk' for millions and such...

Answer (score 0):

You could make it dependent on the comma, e.g. in pseudo code
$i=$input //1k or 1.5k
if contains comma
    remove all commas, replace k with 00
else
    replace k with 000

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "This is a 1,5k String and 1k ";

echo replaceThousands($s);

function replaceThousands($s)
{
    $regex = "/(\d?,?\d)k/";
    $m = preg_match_all($regex, $s, $matches);

    foreach($matches[1] as $i => $match)
    {
        $new = str_replace(",", ".", $match);
        $new = 1000*$new;
        $s = preg_replace("/" .$match."k/", $new, $s);
    }

    return $s;
}
```